# Problema con la librería fstream en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

gracias por ayudarme, tengo un problema y esque estoy haciendo uso de la librería de fstream
y stdlib.h para trabajar con archivos y ficheros `#include"fstream"` `#include"stdlib.h"`
en el IDE de c++.

lo que quiero hacer es introducir un numero dentro de un archivo de texto, guardarlo y después usar la función `getline(miarchivo,variable_que_lee); cout<<variable_que_lee;`  para imprimir en la consola los números que contenga el archivo de texto .txt, ya cambie las variables por tipo entero `int` y usé todos los métodos pero no me funciona me da error este es el código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


string linea_1;
string linea_2;
string linea_3;

int main(){
    
    ifstream archivo("prueba.txt");
    
    getline(archivo,linea_1);
    cout<<linea_1<<endl;
    
    getline(archivo,linea_2);
    cout<<linea_2<<endl;
    
    
    getline(archivo,linea_3);
    cout<<linea_3<<endl;

    
    cout<<"\n\n\t"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

como ejemplo están las variables `string` que sean `int` para almacenar un numero, mismo numero que sea el valor de un numero dentro del archivo del texto en pocas palabras,

quiero que mi programa lea un documento de texto que contendrá números enteros, y que esos números enteros mi programa los lea y los guarde en una variable.

GRACIAS :D.

Comment: Puedes usar `>>` como si fuera `cin`.

Comment: *No me funciona me da error* ¿Qué error recibes?

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y a mí me funciona. Si no te compila, debe ser porque llamas a `system("pause")` y en ningún momento incluyes la cabecera correspondiente (`conio.h`). Si compila y no te muestra nada, el archivo no existe, no lo encuentra o está vacío. Por cierto, de momento no le estás dando uso a `stdlib.h` así que puedes quitarlo. También sugiero que uses `cin.get()` en lugar de `system("pause")`.

Answer (score 1):

La función `std::getline` como su nombre indica, lee una línea de texto. Se diseñó para leer datos que ocupan una línea pero que contienen caracteres que interfieren con la lectura de datos con formato, por ejemplo el espacio ( ).

##### Ejemplo de lectura de datos.

Puedes ver la diferencia de comportamiento de `std::getline` contra `operator>>` en este ejemplo:

###### `archivo.txt`

```
Atanagildo Pérez de Antequera Rodríguez
97
Sisebuto Martín de la Sierra Zorrilla
83
```

Supon que el archivo contiene registros de personas un nombre (con sus apellidos) en una línea y una edad en la siguiente.

Si leemos la edad con el operador de lectura con formato (`operator >>`):

```
std::string nombre;
int edad;

if (std::ifstream{"archivo.txt"})
{
    archivo >> nombre;
    archivo >> edad;
}
```

En la variable `nombre` tendremos `Atanagildo` y en la variable `edad` tendremos nada; esto sucede porque el archivo de lectura tiene un apuntador que apunta hasta donde se ha leído el archivo, antes de leer nada está justo al principio del contenido del archivo:

| A | t | a | n | a | g | i | l | d | o |  | P | é | r | e | z |  | d | e |  | A | n | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ^ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Cuando extraes con el operador de lectura con formato, este operador lee hasta encontrar un espacio y sitúa el apuntador en la siguiente unidad de información:

| A | t | a | n | a | g | i | l | d | o |  | P | é | r | e | z |  | d | e |  | A | n | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ^ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Entonces, al intentar leer un número, nos encontramos con algo que no es un número y la lectura falla (por eso `edad` no tendrá nada).

---

Cuando leemos con `std::getline` la lectura se hace hasta encontrar un salto de línea:

```
std::string nombre;
int edad;

if (std::ifstream{"archivo.txt"})
{
    std::getline(archivo, nombre);
    archivo >> edad;
}
```

Con esto sí que funcionaría el ejemplo.

##### Solución.

Si tu archivo contiene números separados por espacio o salto de línea, no necesitas usar `std::getline` puedes hacer la lectura con formato directamente sobre un `int`:

```
int main(){

    using namespace std;

    ifstream archivo("prueba.txt");
    
    int linea_1;
    archivo >> linea_1;
    cout << linea_1 << '\n';
    
    int linea_2;
    archivo >> linea_2;
    cout << linea_2 << '\n';

    int linea_3;
    archivo >> linea_3;
    cout << linea_3 << '\n';

    cout << "\n\n\t" << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```